# Get line number in Elements window of Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, Tools -> Developer Tools -> Elements tab.  There are no line numbers next to the source code.  Is there a way to toggle them on?

Comment: To put it another way: possibly Chrome *could* show you line numbers, but they wouldn't necessarily correspond to line numbers in the original source, due to dynamic alteration of the DOM structure. I understand this might be useful if you were modifying a document that you could guarantee was not dynamically altered by scripts, but I still think there's no way to do it.

Comment: It can be useful - if you're using a plugin to validate your HTML and it's giving you line numbers from the same source in the browser, then the line numbers given are perfectly relevant

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't know how useful it will be, but you can right click on the html element in the Elements tab, select "Copy as HTML" and paste the results in your favorite text editor.  That will give you line numbers for the DOM as it exists at the point where you copy it.

Like the comments point out, this will not correspond to source line numbers.

Comment: Such a pitty. Line numbers of the console are very helpful when you print a lot of information when developing, especially for the single-page-applications. It should not relate to the document structure at all. I can remember a line number, then easily go back to it instead of been lost in the verbose new information (which is also necessary and useful).

Comment: Or when sharing your screen when debugging.  The developer on the phone can reference line numbers instead of saying, "That div there ... no the other div.   No the one beneath that one"

Answer (score 22):

There is no way to show number line in developer area. You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in the webpage where you want to see the line on code.
Good luck

Comment: This it's great, but this does not render code that has been injected by a client-side app.`view-source` only shows the response from the server.

Answer (score 12):

If you go to View Page Source, this will show the current line numbers. Either right-click -> View Page Source, or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Mac.

For what it's worth, I needed this because I was getting a javascript error with a line number. The dev tools weren't showing this snippet in the regular source tab, presumably because it was embedded in HTML and I had a compilation error (stupid missing comma).

Comment: I dont need to see it all the time, so this worked great.

Answer (score 7):

Press "F12" or go the Developer Tools. Click on the Sources tab double click the already selected file in the pane to the left. See screenshot of this web page below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have a line number because it's the parsed and corrected version of your HTML code and the line numbers might be very different from what you see in you code editor. The best way to find exactly the same element is to add an ID attribute to the element and then use document.querySelectorAll('#CUSTOM_ID');
If you want to see the unchanged HTML (what browser received from server) just right click on the page and choose **view page source**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer because it goes outside of Dev Tool, but a work around to get the line number for those still looking for an answer.

1. In Chrome Develop Tools click on Elements.
2. Right click on the < html > element (it is one of the first lines).
3. Select "Copy Element".
4. Paste the copied text into a text editor that can show line numbers.
5. Adjust the line number by how many lines down the < html > element was. For example: If <! DOCTYPE html > is the first and only line and < html > is on the second line, subtract 1 from the line numbers shown in the text editor.

Suggested use: When JavaScript modifies the DOM, the "Elements" tab provides an accurate representation of the DOM as it currently is.

Answer (score -2):

Try chrome extension **[Go to line](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-line/pdaociefbdibmlmebaflgmjilnljkcpn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)**:

Comment: it's a good practice to copy essential parts of the link content here

Answer (score -5):

I don't know if Chrome DevTools has changed since the post, but you can do this now:

Expand the Error by clicking the arrow next to it and then click on the line that says stack(...) and it will expand into the same error message plus the source line where it occurred.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Question says nothing about errors - just the DOM inspector