# How can I see the line number for CSS style of selected element in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: css, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome Developer Tools, I'd like to know what the line number of each CSS style applied to the selected element is. Firebug in Firefox does this and its real handy.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get line number in Elements window of Chrome Developer Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257399/get-line-number-in-elements-window-of-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: You can also use Firebug lite in google chrome :) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firebug-lite-for-google-c/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench

Comment: @NathanLee Yes that question is similar, however what I am really getting at is that Firebug displays the correct line numbers and Chrome Dev Tools does not.

Comment: Here I have many commands 
http://www.wepstech.com/how-to-count-number-of-line-in-project/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the number at the end of the file name, following the `:` sign.

For example, `layout9.css?nocached4:1` means the property is declared at line `1`. This is typical of minified CSS files, which tend to be a single line.

The difference in the screenshot between Firebug and Chrome Developer Tools could be that Firebug is configured to use CSS source maps, so it is able to show the correct line numbers regardless. Check to see the Chrome Developer Tools has the setting "Enable CSS source maps" checked.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools - Settings - Enable CSS Source Maps]

Comment: The CSS on the page in the screenshot is not minified. Firebug shows the correct line number, Chrome does not. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Apparently, Chrome believes the file is minified. Try in a different site and you'll see the numbers correspond to the correct lines. Also, try clicking the file name to see how Chrome interprets the file in the screenshot.

Comment: It could be that Firebug is configured to use CSS source maps so it is able to show the correct line numbers regardless. Check to see the Chrome Developer Tools has the setting "Enable CSS source maps" checked.

Comment: You're right--it works correctly on other sites. Chrome must find something funny with this site or css file. When I click on the file name, the CSS file is shown with multiple lines exactly as the actual file is shown. Oh well.

Comment: CSS source maps were enabled. I tried disabling and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: What about line breaks? Could they be somehow malformed?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but hope this helps someone who stumbles on this thread.

The problem is that your End of Line (EOL, \r\n) chars have somehow become just Carriage Return (CR, \r) chars. So most code editors and the build-in Chrome DevTools code editor shows the code normal (with normal EOL) but the Styles pane in Chrome DevTools parses the CSS file as one line without the Line Feed (LF, \n) char.

To fix this issue just add \n chars to all lonely \r chars. This can be done with most code editors using search & replace.

Comment: (Even later, but: It helped tremendously! Thank you! ^^)

Comment: I found out that this Chars issue was happening because my Dreamweaver Settings (CS6 on a MAC) under preferences were: 'Preferences/Code Type Format/CR Macintosh/. I changed the 'Code Type Format' to 'LF(Unix)' and re-opened the file and it automatically fixed it.