# Get the line number in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Let's say if the page has loading option and I load with several load clicks after that if I press ctrl+u it does get the final load number values but it ignores all the loading clicks. Whereas in developer tools (with inspect) view we get everything but no line numbers. How to get line number on that occasion?

Comment: An example would be any social network website. I tried with research gate and also facebook where you get the list of people in the network or the live feed respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get line number in Elements window of Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257399/get-line-number-in-elements-window-of-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Developer tool source code find the number line in VS code.Use this shortcut key
"ctrl + G"

process :

inspect ===> source ===>ctrl+P(Find a file name)===>ctrl+G(Find the which line of the code)